# Asking questions about a previously accepted answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

If a user accepts an answer to a question and then later asks a question trying to debug the answer that was accepted because it didn't solve their first question, is it right to vote the question as a duplicate?

The premise being that shouldn't the user really be trying to understand the answer that they accepted on the question where they accepted it?  Because why would a user accept an answer in the first place if it doesn't work to solve their problem.

For example, these two questions:

1. [How can I make stopwatch in C# that displays only seconds and milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518984/how-can-i-make-stopwatch-in-c-sharp-that-displays-only-seconds-and-milliseconds)
2. [How to make stopwatch visible? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537609/how-to-make-stopwatch-visible-c-sharp)

Comment: There could be situations where an answer is correct for the MCVE or information provided by the user, but something else in their code interacts with the fix in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is good for a user to ask a second question instead of just expanding on their existing finished one. Strongly related is this discussion from a few years ago about ["chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

When a user modifies their question to include an answer then something wrong has happened. Not only is the answer often ruined at that point, but the question has changed and the first wave of users who could have potentially been answering has seen it in its original state and moved on.

Asking a new question is the correct path. The main problem here is that the original question was kind of mediocre, and the follow up question just took that style and ran with it. This produced another mediocre quality post which was strongly related to the first post.

Either way, in general this is the approach users should be using. Ideally they would post questions which are of higher quality, and if anything the existing posts you note should be actioned more based on their content than on the weak link between them (which upon inspection does seem to be what happened/is happening).

Comment: It's even better if they include a link to their previous question.